# Kite ticker feed for backtrader

Tags: python, kite, backtrader

I am using backtrader for testing my strategy but my broker i.e kite api is not directly supported by backtrader. I want to either use a dynamic CSV or use kite websocket/ticker with backtrader for live trading

Comment: Kite is not currently supported. You may explore building out a broker class for kite as backtrader is open source. Several such extensions have been built, notably [binance](https://github.com/rodrigo-brito/backtrader-binance-bot) and [ccxt](https://github.com/Dave-Vallance/bt-ccxt-store).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am building an extension for kite now.